# Moduli spaces of arithmetic varieties with isomorphic $l$-adic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Given a positive integer $d$, a rational prime $l$ and a number field $K$, is it sensible to consider the moduli stack of $d$-dimensional varieties over $K$ whose $l$-adic cohomology rings are isomorphic as Galois modules?